# How to map a 2D lookup table to array (python)?

Tags: python, numpy, lookup-tables

I have three 2D-arrays of same shape, lets call them theta, phi and A.
Let theta and phi be angles to the normal vector seen from different distances on a surface:

```
size = 100 # this value is fixed
x = np.arange(-size, size)
y = np.arange(-size, size)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
theta = np.arctan((xx**2+yy**2)**0.5 / 100) # angle from distance 100
phi = np.arctan((xx**2+yy**2)**0.5 / 1000) # angle from distance 1000
```

And let A be a 2D map of measured values where the x axis is theta and the y axis is phi in known and linear steps (which is actually not the same shape as theta and phi). What I need is the values of A(theta,phi) expressed as A(x,y).
It seems I can't figure out how to convert A(theta,phi) to A(x,y), even though I know both theta(x,y) and phi(x,y).

What I tried:
Via scipy.interpolate.interp2d I can map A to the same number of rows and columns as theta and phi. Now I can iterate over the indices and guess/round the best matching indices in my array

```
B = np.zeros(A.shape)
for i in range(0,A.shape[0]):
  for j in range(0,A.shape[1]):
    B[i,j] = A[int(f_theta*theta[i,j]),int(f_phi*phi[i,j])]
```

Where f_theta and f_phi are prefactors determined by the measured step length of a index step.
This looks like very bad and inefficient coding to me, and like a crude approximation of what I actually want to do (which is an inverse interpolation mapping?). It reminds me of lookup-tables, coordinate transforms and interpolation, but with none of those keywords I found something appropriate to solve the problem.
My python experience shouts out that there will be a module/function for this which I do not know.

Edit about restrictions:
the range of the axis in A(theta, phi) is larger than the range of theta(x,y) and phi(x,y), such that a mapped value always exists.
I do not need to map B back to A, so there are no issues with missing values.
Many values in the map A(theta, phi) would never be used.

Edit about clarity:
I will give an example with small matrices, hoping to clarify things:

```
# phi given in degrees
phi = np.array([
    [2,1,2],
    [1,0,1],
    [2,1,2],
])
# theta given in degrees
theta = np.array([
    [6,4,6],
    [4,0,5],
    [6,5,6],
])
# A[0,0] is the value at phi=0deg, theta=0deg
# A[0,1] is the value at phi=1deg, theta=0deg
# A[1,1] is the value at phi=1deg, theta=1deg etc
# this is a toy example, the actual A cannot be constructed by a simple rule
A = np.array([
    [0.0,0.1,0.2],
    [1.0,1.1,1.2],
    [2.0,2.1,2.2],
    [3.0,3.1,3.2],
    [4.0,4.1,4.2],
    [5.0,5.1,5.2],
    [6.0,6.1,6.2],
])
# what I want to reach:
B = [[6.2,4.1,6.2],
     [4.1,0.0,5.1],
     [6.2,5.1,6.2]]
```

I need to clarify that I did some simplifications here:

1) For a given theta I can check the corresponding phi by looking in the table:
theta[i,j] corresponds to phi[i,j]. But the construction of the example is too simplified, they do not e.g. share the same origin, it is noisy data and I therefore cannot give an analytical expression theta(phi) or phi(theta)

2) The values in my actual theta and phi are floats, and my actual A measures in non-integer steps too (e.g. 0.45 deg per step in theta direction, 0.2 deg per step in phi direction)

3) in principle, as there is a strict relation between theta and phi, I only need a specific 1D "trace" of values A to find B, but I do not understand how to find this trace, nor how to create B out of the trace. This trace in the example would be [A[0,0],A[4,1],A[5,1],A[6,2]] = [0.0,4.1,5.1,6.2]

Comment: Is there a restriction on *θ (x₀, y₀) ≠ θ (x₁, y₁)* ? And the same for phi and also for A both in (θ, ϕ) and (x, y)? If not, then why should you be able to do this inverse transform as there could be multiple matching values in the reverse direction.

Comment: I edited about the restrictions. I hope I understood correctly, thanks for the remark

Comment: I mean more that say A(4,7) might equal A(8,2) so given the value of A, how do you know if you wanted to map back to (4,7) or (8,2)?

Comment: that may happen, but it's not a problem since I want to map the other way round: with given theta(x,y) and phi(x,y) I want to find the corresponding A(x,y), where my actual A is an array over theta and phi. Also in the case that theta(8,2) and phi(8,2) both equal theta(4,7) and phi(4,7), respectively, is not a problem. It will just result in A(4,7)=A(8,2), which is what I want

Comment: The question is still somewhat unclear. 1) Given theta you can always compute phi, and vice versa. So why not reduce this to a 1-dimensional problem? 2) What do yo mean, exactly, with "the values of A(theta,phi) expressed as A(x,y)"? Do you mean, given (theta, phi) you want to know (x,y)? 3) Maybe add a toy example for `A`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Andrei. I tried to address them with a little toy example. It is hard to explain, and I'm grateful for your help pointing out what is hardest to understand.

Comment: Thanks. I think I see what you mean now. One more question. So, the values in phi an theta matrices are not necessarily divisible by the step, right? So, phi[1,1] can be, say, 4.72, while the step for A is, say, 0.2, right? And then you want some sort of interpolation.

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do, e.g., a bilinear interpolation:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

delta = [1.0, 1.0] # theta, phi
points = [np.arange(s)*d for s, d in zip(A.shape, delta)]
xi = np.stack((theta, phi), axis = -1)
B = interpn(points, A, xi)
```

This gives:

```py
print(B)
[[6.2 4.1 6.2]
 [4.1 0.  5.1]
 [6.2 5.1 6.2]]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and acceptance, I was busy with other things last week. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again also for the help in clarifying my question, as it was a bit difficult to wrap my head around it